# Cannot select certain vertices

Tags: selection-tools

Blender 2.79

[image: Trying to select vertices]

No matter which mouse button I click, I cannot select or deselect any of the vertices on a curve. This seems to also apply to when I am editing vertices on a mesh and "Limit Selection to Visible" is disabled. However, the shortcut keys of "(De)Select All", "Invert Selection", and so on do work. I've tried rebooting the entire computer and still I have this problem.

**[image: Trying to select vertices.mp4]**

Pressed every single side of the mouse.

Comment: Please update your gif. Delete the current gif and show a new one. Show where you press [a] to deselect. Then show box select or click on a single point.  Please tell us what happens when you close Blender completely, Start Blender and start a new file with a curve.

Comment: Answer updated with exclusive information

Comment: Do you have any unusual mouse such a mouse [without wheel button] requiring slight special configuration for use with Blender?

Comment: Basic SteelSeries Sensei, Middle-Click = Mouse Wheel, 2 extra buttons on either side.

Answer (score 0):

Click with the other side of the Mouse

---

Press 
<kbd>a</kbd>
 one or twice so that nothing is selected and the image looks dim not bright.  Its a toggle.

Then Click Only

---

Then use
<kbd>b</kbd>
for box select and you should see a difference.

My opinion is that everything is selected in you original question.

You can also press 
<kbd>W</kbd>
then select subdivide to have more variation in your selection.

Perhaps you  already know this.

Comment: `a` does make a difference. `b` does not make a difference. `w` just splits the line, but still cannot select anything.

Comment: Updated the image.

Comment: "The other side of the Mouse" isn't especially more "exclusive information". If you see the link (because gif went over 8mb) you'll see I have pressed every side of the mouse.

Comment: Exclusive information was a failed joke.  I cannot recreate your problem.  I have seen on rare occasion such problems with Blender.  I would close Blender and restart your machine.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check these in top right in *Edit Mode*, might be on a different selection mode.

Comment: I'm not seeing these icons in the top-right of the picture I posted.

Answer (score 0):

In *Object Mode*, select the curve you want to edit.
Navigate from the *Layout* workspace to the *Geometry Nodes* workspace.
Go into *Edit Mode* and from there the points are selectable.

I'm unsure if this is a bug or if there is a better way to fix this (like some random button I may have pressed at some point messing things up), but it worked for me.
(Using Blender 3.5)